# Trigger Tkinter events from a different class in Python

Tags: python, class, tkinter, triggers

So I've been trying to get into using classes in my tkinter projects, but I seem to have trouble understanding exactly how classes interact. Especially when tkinter is involved. I can accesses variables and values and pass those around, but I can't seem to figure out how to do triggers.

My current problem is with trying to trigger an event from a different class.
A simple version of the problem is this:

```
from tkinter import *

class Area:
    def __init__(self):
        self.can = Canvas(width=100, height=100, bg="green")
        self.can.pack(in_=window)
        self.can.bind("<Button-3>", self.test)
        self.square = self.can.create_rectangle(25, 25, 75, 75)

    def test(self, event):
        self.can.delete("all")

class Trigger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.button = Button(text="click me", command=?)
        self.button.pack(in_=window)

window = Tk()
Area()
Trigger()
window.mainloop()
```

It creates a green canvas with a square in the middle. When you right click the canvas, the square is removed. I then try to trigger that same behavior from a different class, demonstrated here with a button.

Problem is, I can't for the life of me figure out what to have as a command on the button.

I've tried `command=Area.test`, but then I get "

> TypeError: test() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and
>   'event'"

I've tried `command=Area.test(Area, "event")` and `command=Area.test(self, "event")`, but they return:

> AttributeError: type object 'Area' has no attribute 'can'

and

> AttributeError: type object 'Area' has no attribute 'can'

I also tried `Area().test("event)`, which gave no error but gave me 2 instances of the canvas, one with the square and one without. The button did nothing then.

Looked into inheritance, so I tried that by putting Area as inheritance on the Trigger class, then do `command=self.test("event")`
But then got:

> AttributeError: 'Trigger' object has no attribute 'can'

So I'm out of ideas.. Am I doing the `__init__`part wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to use a function both as a target of an event and as the value for a `command` attribute, you should make the `event` argument optional. You can do that by giving it a default value of `None`:

```
def test(self, event=None):
    self.can.delete("all")
```

Second, the `Trigger` object needs to be given the instance of the `Area` object so that it can call methods on that object. There are several ways to do this, but the most straight-forward is to pass it in when creating the object. This means you need to modify `Trigger.__init__` to accept the parameter, and then you need to pass it in when creating the object.

This is how to modify the `__init__` method:

```
class Trigger:
    def __init__(self, area):
        self.button = Button(text="click me", command=area.test)
        self.button.pack(in_=window)
```

This is how to pass the `Area` object to the `Trigger` object:

```
area=Area()
Trigger(area)
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully, thanks! Do I have to first state the area=Area() though, wouldn't Trigger(Area()) be the same thing?